# Force IsPostBack become false in Controls.Add(new control);

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Im using ASP.NET 3.5 and WebForms + jQuery, when I added a UserControl (ACSX) in runtime using a button click event, the event page_load in the custom acsx show false in IsPostBack, so when its happens the customs controls inside the control could not initialize. Then I show the acsx in a modal dialog trough jQueryUI.Modal

Any ideas how to force IsPostBack to false, in the control load?

Regards.

Comment: "Show the ASCX in a modal dialog" <-- this sounds like a *new* page/HTTP request is being created and shown in an *iframe* (inside a modal dialog). In this case it makes sense that IsPostBack is false.

Comment: You should refactor your code ideally.

Comment: If I remove the isPostBack code it works, but when I submit the form the fields resets logically

Comment: UpdatePanel, could help? I use it a few minutes ago with PostBack in Optional and couldn't get it works

Comment: @pst, is there a way to reuse the existing page/HTTP request for load my user control? thanks in advance

Comment: Please show cs-code that render ascx-control. As far as I understand call chain next: ui.modal -> webservice -> reder ascx control -> return markup to modal, is it right?

Comment: page.load > button click event (server side) > render ascx control > ui.modal

Comment: Can you show the code? Preferably refactor it so that you only have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a session variable that works alongside IsPostBack i.e.

Control that is creating control (Code)

```
Session["reload"] = true;
placeholder.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/path/to/control.ascx"));
```

UserControl code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var reload = Session["reload"];
    if(!IsPostback || (reload != null && (bool)reload))
    {
      Session["reload"] = null;//reset the session var
      //do load
    }
}
```

Minor modification and ability to reload on demand

Comment: stuff like this should go in the controls own Attributes collection to be sure not to bloat the environment and keep a single point of responsibility.

*var ctl = (UserControl)LoadControl("~/path/to/control.ascx"); ctl.Attributes["reload"] = "true"; placeholder.Controls.Add(ctl)*

Comment: Nice addition Pauli and far cleaner

Comment: Additionally, you could also consider the `Items` collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx), instead of the Session.  `Items` only persists during the current request.